# What's the difference between repression and suppression?

Tags: terminology

These two terms are closely related, and thus easily confusable as synonymous. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 4):

[Repression](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/repression) is the **unconscious** exclusion of impulses, desires, or fears from the conscious mind, while [suppression](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/suppression) is the **conscious** exclusion of similar thoughts.

Comment: this is one of the shortest and sweetest, yet succinct and accurate answers

Comment: Thanks! I considered going into more depth, but brevity is the soul of wit and all that ;-)

Comment: I know people tend to favor depth here, I always like to upvote newcomers and give encouragement and constructive feedback if poss. I am sure you'll get more votes if you go into more detail, however it is spot on :) and welcome again

Comment: yvw.. its always good to have new people with enthusiasm. :)